# Issue with fitvid.js when appending container via jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I've been using [FitVid](http://fitvidsjs.com/) for months now and have never encountered any problems with it, but now I'm having an issue and I can't seem to fathom out the cause.

I'm using it with a modified version of this [portfolio plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/) but for whatever reason it doesn't seem to work. I'm thinking it's because the fitvid container is appended via jQuery?

Here is the jQuery function that appends all of the content I need;

```
Preview.prototype = {
    create : function() {
        this.$iframeWrapper = $('<iframe src=""frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        this.$fitVid = $( '<div class="fitvid"></div>' ).append( this.$iframeWrapper );
        this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$fitVid  );
    }
}
```

I've double and triple checked and I'm calling FitVid correctly and the main script is working fine (It's working on another part of the site) and I've tried calling the grid script before and after the FitVid one and nothing seems to work.

If it helps [this is the page](http://outpost.purenine.com/our-work/) I'm having problems on. You can see the video iframe and `.fitvid` div are outputting fine, but it's not resizing correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can help here, it seems as you abandoned this problem.

1. your `.colio-content` class is set to `display: none`
2. it has no height

If I manually add those in DOM-inspector, it seems to work ok. But you would probably want to add some floating then.